# Member function pointer of forward declared class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undefined-behavior

The header `common.h` forward declares a class `Test` and a function receiving a member function pointer:

```
class Test;

void func(const Test &t, int (Test::*f)() const, int x, int y);
```

In the source file `target.cpp`, I define the function such that

```
#include "common.h"

void func(const Test &t, int (Test::*f)() const, int x, int y) {
    std::cout << "f: " << (t.*f)() << ", x: " << x << ", y: " << y << std::endl;
}
```

In my main file, I define the class `Test` and use the function `func`:

```
class Test {
public:
    int example() const { return 1; }
};

#include "common.h"

int main() {
    Test t;
    func(t, &Test::example, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xbbbbbbbb);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this is a bit smelly since pointers to member functions are sometimes more than a simple pointer. But the resulting behavior is a bit overwhelming: The given parameters `0xaaaaaaaa` and `0xbbbbbbbb` won't be passed correctly to the function. Or to be more precise, the function `func` interprets the given stack differently than the data is pushed on the stack by the caller. The size of `f` depends on whether the class is only forward declared or actually defined. The output compiled with Visual Studio 2013 is:

```
f: 1, x: 0, y: 2130567168
```

I thought, *if* a forward declaration is sufficient, it *really* doesn't matter whether there's a definition given or not.

Comment: `0xaaaaaaaa` and `0xbbbbbbbb` are not representable as `int` (under windows calling conventions, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx)). The narrowing conversion invokes undefined behaviour. Have you tried using smaller numbers?

Comment: I choose these values in order to see them clearly on my stack. Of course, it does not work either if you choose smaller values. And I thought, the narrowing is done during compilation since these values are literals and bound to integer values.

Comment: IMHO it's not correct to get a function of forward declared class, because this function could be either virtual or not

Comment: @borisbn: That's true but neither g++ nor clang++ nor Visual C++ complains about this issue.

Answer (score 6):

By default, MSVC favours speed over correctness with pointers to member. You can force it to work according to the standard by passing the compiler flag [`/vmg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yad46a6z.aspx).

Comment: Oh, that's just great! I lost a whole day on this problem.

Comment: @phlipsy The same happened to me (i.e. I also learned of this flag the hard way).

Comment: Do you have some additional information, links etc. on this point?

Comment: @phlipsy Just the link to MSDN in the answer, but it should do as a starting point.